# Storing Chunks of a CSV file in an indexed array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a data set with pairs for every day in a month, where the first values are times and the second values are locations:

```
12:00, Location 1,
1:00, Location 2,
//etc.
```

and each day may have more or less (or the same amount) of values as any other day. The CSV is structured in a way that each day's worth of data is separated by a row with two empty columns delimited by commas.

```
// Day 1:
12:00, Location 1,
1:00: Location 2,
, ,
// Day 2
12:15, Location 3,
1:45, Location 1,
```

My aim is to parse through the CSV with PHP and store each day's worth of data as a new array, so perhaps `month[0]` is equal to an array with the first day's values, `month[1]` is the second day, and so forth. I've tried using multiple loops but am having difficulty starting a new, multidimensional array every time I hit a 'null' or empty value. So far I've tried:

```
<?php

$contents = file_get_contents('test.csv');
$newArray = explode(',', $contents); 
$count = count($newArray);

for($c=0; $c < $count; $c+=2) {

$time = $newArray[$c];
$location = $newArray[$c + 1];

if ( $time == null ) { echo 'empty'; } else {

echo '<li>' . $time . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $location . '</li>';

} }
```

Yet the if never returns true. However if I test $newArray[25] (the first empty cell in my csv) against 'null' it returns true.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Please add your code attempts to the question

Comment: @Rizier123 In retrospect it was really dumb not to post the code. I've updated my post. I look forward to your response as I've really been scratching my head on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding finding a null value within a csv, try this:

```
if ( trim($time) === "") { // do something }
```